# C# Read XML from fpage of XPS stream

Tags: c#, xml, stream, xps

I´d like to read the XML structure of an fpage Element in an XPS as Stream.

So to further explain what i want to do:

If you save a .xps you can rename it to a zip archive then you can read the xml e.g. 
 xps\Documents\1\Pages\1.fpage

Now I want to read this xml structure in my C# program.
Because save to disc, rename, navigate, extract, read, delete isn´t a good option i have this xps file already available as a stream in my program. 
So the question is how can i access this XPS structure from stream and read it´s xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if found the answer myself (isn´t that hard if you know how^^). 
You need **System.IO.Packaging.Package** and a Reference to **ReachFramework** then create a new XpsDocument and via XmlReader you can read the XML structure. 
Small sample for reading first page:

```
XpsDocument xpsFromStream = new XpsDocument(Package.Open(stream)); //ReachFramework
IXpsFixedDocumentSequenceReader fixedDocSeqReader = xpsFromStream.FixedDocumentSequenceReader;

if (fixedDocSeqReader != null)
{
    XmlReader pageContentReader = fixedDocSeqReader.FixedDocuments[0].FixedPages[0].XmlReader;
    //Sample:
    while (pageContentReader.Read())
    {
        if (pageContentReader.Name == "Path")
            //Do stuff
    } 
}
```